# Sequelize - Object with nested fields

Tags: node.js, database, sequelize.js

I'm migrating from Dynamo (Dynamoose) to PostgreSQL (Sequelize). In Dynamoose we can have records like this:

```
{
  id: 1234
  name: {
    first: "John",
    last: "Doe"
  }
}
```

Can I do the same in Sequelize?

Comment: Depend on how you want to store this - in two tables or in one table in something like JSON field

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB is a NoSQL database and Postgres is an SQL database. It would be better to store the two as first_name and last_name separately. If you have some other reason to not go with that solution then you can always opt to store the JSON as string in SQL as VARCHAR type. Since you are using Postgres you can use the JSON type. Sharing the link for your reference https://sequelize.org/v6/manual/other-data-types.html.